# Missing boosts filesystem lib after build

Tags: c++, boost

I have the latest version of boost (1.58). After building it via command line on windows:

```
bootstrap
.\b2
```

I add boost dir to path and boost/stage/lib to lib path.

I add #include  to my code and when I compile I get an error saying:

Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib' E:\SourceControl\zombiegame\ZombieGame\Projects\Windows\LINK    ZombieGame

I'm not including any lib myself so guessing boost is doing this via the code, but this file doesn't exist in the stage/lib path.

The closest I have is libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib but you can see it's -gd- not -sgd- like it's asking for. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a configuration that is not provided by boost. Boost build its libraries with different settings for Debug/Release and (here I think is the point) for Runtime library (static lib/dynamic dll/single threaded/multithread). From the names I would guess you have a static or single threaded config. Try to change that one and you should find one of those provided by boost build.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do that.

Comment: On project properties, C/C++ section code generation page